# Trouble running java command line tool inside an automation program

Tags: java, command-line, command

I am using a .bat file, which is reliant on a .jar file. I have java (jdk/jre) installed on my system. If I run a command on this command line api via cmd (e.g. nscmd --help), everything works fine.

However, I want to run commands inside another program (Automise www.automise.com). If I do so, with the command line tools in another folder to Java, I get the infamous "java is not a recognised keyword...etc" error. If I put the command line tools in the same folder as Java, I get this error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
Program returned code  : 1

How can I successfully run the command line tools?The tool is this: http://www.newservers.com/language/en/documentation/reference-nscmd.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the directory java is in to your path variable.